# I keep getting this question wrong. Counting Bits using javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary

This is the question.
Given an integer n, return an array ans of length n + 1 such that for each i (0 <= i <= n), ans[i] is the number of 1's in the binary representation of i.

https://leetcode.com/problems/counting-bits/

And this is my solution below.
If the input is 2, expected output should be [0,1,1] but I keep getting [0,2,2]. Why is that???

```js
var countBits = function(n) {
    //n=3. [0,1,2,3]
    var arr=[0];
     for (var i=1; i<=n; i++){
         var sum = 0;
         var value = i;
         while(value != 0){
             sum += value%2;
             value /= 2;
         }
         arr.push(sum);
     }
    return arr;
};

console.log(countBits(3));
```

Comment: `value /= 2` does actual floating point division, not integer division as you seem to think. (Basic debugging should have told you this much.)

Comment: You need to set `value` to the floor of `value/2` (to account for the remainder you've already handled).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I totally forgot about that

Answer (score 4):

You're doing way too much work.

Suppose `b` is the largest power of 2 corresponding to the first bit in `i`. Evidently, `i` has exactly one more `1` in its binary representation than does `i - b`. But since you're generating the counts in order, you've already worked out how many `1`s there are in `i - b`.

The only trick is how to figure out what `b` is. And to do that, we use another iterative technique: as you list numbers, `b` changes exactly at the moment that `i` becomes twice the previous value of `b`:

```js
const countBits = function(n) {
    let arr = [0], bit = 1;
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        if (i == bit + bit) bit += bit;
        arr.push(arr[i - bit] + 1);
    }
    return arr;
};

console.log(countBits(20));
```

This technique is usually called "dynamic programming". In essence, it takes a recursive definition and computes it bottom-up: instead of starting at the desired argument and recursing down to the base case, it starts at the base and then computes each intermediate value which will be needed until it reaches the target. In this case, all intermediate values are needed, saving us from having to think about how to compute only the minimum number of intermediate values necessary.

Comment: Voted up. You might appreciate gog's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72737531/2034787)

Answer (score 3):

Think of it this way: if you know how many ones are there in a number `X`, then you immediately know how many ones are there in `X*2` (the same) and `X*2+1` (one more). Since you're processing numbers in order, you can just push both derived counts to the result and skip to the next number:

```
let b = [0, 1]

for (let i = 1; i <= N / 2; i++) {
    b.push(b[i])
    b.push(b[i] + 1)
}
```

Since we push two numbers at once, the result will be one-off for even N, you have to pop the last number afterwards.

Comment: Voted up. I believe you could make it even more succinct by have one `push` call with two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

use floor():

```
sum += Math.floor(value%2);
value = Math.floor(value/2);
```

I guess your algorithm works for some typed language where integers division results in integers

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very different approach, using the opposite of a `fold` (such as `Array.prototype.reduce`) typically called `unfold`.  In this case, we start with a seed array, perform some operation on it to yield the next value, and recur, until we decide to stop.

We write a generic `unfold` and then use it with a callback which accepts the entire array we've found so far plus `next` and `done` callbacks, and then chooses whether to stop (if we've reached our limit) or continue.  In either case, it calls one of the two callbacks.

It looks like this:

```js
const _unfold = (fn, init) =>
  fn (init, (x) => _unfold (fn, [...init, x]), () => init)

// Number of 1's in the binary representation of each integer in [`0 ... n`]
const oneBits = (n) => _unfold (
  (xs, next, done) => xs .length < n ? next (xs .length % 2 + xs [xs .length >> 1]) : done(),
  [0]
)

console .log (oneBits (20))
```

I have a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/CrossEye/2b4fa82d293bb09e85d83c7cbf21788a) which shows a few more examples of this pattern.

An interesting possible extension would be to encapsulate the handling of the array-to--length-n bit, and make this function trivial.  That's no the only use of such an `_unfold`, but it's probably a common one.  It could look like this:

```js
const _unfold = (fn, init) =>
  fn (init, (x) => _unfold (fn, [...init, x]), () => init)

const unfoldN = (fn, init) => (n) => _unfold (
  (xs, next, done) => xs .length < n ? next (fn (xs)) : done (),
  init
)

const oneBits = unfoldN (
  (xs) => xs .length % 2 + xs [xs .length >> 1], 
  [0]
)

console .log (oneBits (20))
```

Here we have two helper functions that make `oneBits` quite trivial to write.  And those helpers have many potential uses.

Answer (score 0):

I've done like this, with bitwise operators

```
function countBits(n) {
    const arr = new Array(n + 1).fill(0);
    for(let i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        arr[i] = arr[i >>> 1] + (i & 1);
    }
    return arr;
};
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read up on [answering questions well](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering).  While this code looks like it answers the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).